# Merge Function giving empty dataset outcome

Tags: r, merge

I have two datasets one has 1359 observables, while the other 136. Both have the same variables 'city' and 'state' and I am already sure that the city and State names are written perfectly the same in both datasets. The problem is when i use the merge function on R, it is giving an empty dataset to me.

```
blm_pb <- merge(blm_df, pb1, by= c("city","state"))
```

Comment: Please check the `names(blm_df)` and `names(pb1)`.  there may be leading/lagging spaces

Comment: Hello @akrun, I checked: `names(blm_df)` gives:  "city"  "state" "TotalPop" "PovertyRate" and `names(pb1)` return: "city"  "state" "total".

Comment: In that case, there may not be not matching values in those columns.  By default `merge` does inner join

Comment: can you check `intersect(paste(blm_df$city, blm_df$state), paste(pb1$city, pb1$state))`

Comment: `intersect(paste(blm_df$city, blm_df$state), paste(pb1$city, pb1$state))` gives: character(0). It is weird that it does not find matches because i can see in both databases for example city: Portland and state: Oregon

Comment: Can you try `intersect(paste(trimws(blm_df$city), trimws(blm_df$state)), paste(trimws(pb1$city), trimws(pb1$state)))`

Comment: `intersect(paste(trimws(blm_df$city), trimws(blm_df$state)), paste(trimws(pb1$city), trimws(pb1$state)))`:   [1] "Dover Delaware"  "Birmingham Alabama" "Washington District of Columbia" [4] "Fort Lauderdale Florida" "Jacksonville Florida" "Miami Florida"  [7] "Orlando Florida"  "St. Petersburg Florida" "Tampa Florida" [10] "Atlanta Georgia"                 "Hoover Alabama"  "Huntsville Alabama"  (...)   [112] "Waterbury Connecticut"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the columns have leading/lagging spaces.  An option is to first remove the spaces with `trimws`

```
nm1 <- c("city","state")
blm_df[nm1] <- lapply(blm_df[nm1], trimws)
pb1[nm1] <- lapply(pb1[nm1], trimws)
```

Now, the `merge` code should work

```
blm_pb <- merge(blm_df, pb1, by= c("city","state"))
```

By default, the `merge` does an inner join.  If we want to get a full join which includes the full set of union of both `by` columns from the two datasets and it will show `NA` where there is no match

```
blm_pb_full <- merge(blm_df, pb1, by= c("city","state"), all = TRUE)
```

If we need a left join, use `all.x  = TRUE` and for right join, it is `all.y = TRUE`

Comment: Thank you for the help! Now its merging but is there a way i can still merge but the observables with no match are placed by NA in the new column that was added?

Comment: @rauls__ By default, it is a inner join.  You can use `all = TRUE` i.e. `merge(blm_df, pb1, by= c("city","state"), all = TRUE)`  to return non-matches as well which will be NA by default